# Awk regix print params from URL request in access log

Tags: linux, awk

I have an access log file containing the following data, I want to check how many times the &u={yyy} parameter appears and print the corresponding number.

```
192.168.1.1 [2022/07/10 20:00:00] GET /action?t=test&u=123&b=check
192.168.1.2 [2022/07/10 20:00:00] GET /action?t=test&u=122&b=check
192.168.1.1 [2022/07/10 20:00:00] GET /action?t=test&u=122&b=check

Resuls: 
2 122
1 123
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
192.168.1.1 [2022/07/10 20:00:00] GET /action?t=test&u=123&b=check
192.168.1.2 [2022/07/10 20:00:00] GET /action?t=test&u=122&b=check
192.168.1.1 [2022/07/10 20:00:00] GET /action?t=test&u=122&b=check
```

then

```
awk 'match($0,"&u=[^&]*"){arr[substr($0, RSTART+3, RLENGTH-3)]++}END{for(i in arr){print arr[i],i}}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
2 122
1 123
```

Explanation: I use 2 [string functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html), first is `match` which does set `RSTART`, `RLENGTH` and its' return value is used as condition, so action is executed only if match was found. Action is simple increase of value of array under key based on match without 3 first characters (`&u=`). After all lines are processed I output value key pairs of arrays. **Disclaimer**: this solution assumes any order of output lines is acceptable.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 0):

If the logfile always look the same:

```
cat logfile | awk -F\& '{print $2}'| uniq -c
```

Comment: Its show like this:    1 u=123
      2 u=122